# How can I show the textfield in the UICollectionviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, xcode, header, uitextfield, uicollectionview

I checked the header section and footer section in xcode,I add a **textfield** to that header in *UIcollectionviewcontroller* but when the app runs it not showing the *textfield*?why?

Answer (score 1):

you should subclass UICollectionReusableView, add your outlet to the subclass, modify the reuse identifier of the header view in the storyboard and implement collectionView:viewForSupplementaryViewOfKind:atIndexPath from the datasource. check the apple documentation.

for example:

```
-(UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

HeaderView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

//set the delegate of the textfield to the view controller
headerView.textField.delegate = self;

return headerView;
}
```

Comment: ... i don't have any, desolé

Comment: any one know how can i implement search on the header of collectionviewcontroller